# xfreerdp multiple screens don't work

Tags: linux, xfreerdp, bspwm

I have dual monitor setup. I can't get `xfreerdp` to launch full screen on both monitors.

```
$ xfreerdp /monitor-list
      * [0] 1920x1080   +0+0
        [1] 1920x1080   +1920+0
```

`xfreerdp /multimon` - just launches inside window

`xfreerdp /monitors:0,1 /multimon` - just launches inside window

`xfreerdp /monitors:1,2 /multimon` - launches full screen on monitor 0

`xfreerdp /monitors:0 /multimon` - launches full screen on monitor 0

`xfreerdp /monitors:1 /multimon` - launches full screen on monitor 0

FreeRDP version 2.1.0

I am using Arch Linux

I have `bspwm` as windows manager, `picom` as a compositor.

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00
   1680x1050     59.95
   1440x900      59.89
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02
   1280x960      60.00
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25
   720x576       50.00
   720x480       59.94
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00
   1680x1050     59.95
   1440x900      59.89
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02
   1280x960      60.00
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25
   720x576       50.00
   720x480       59.94
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93
USB-C-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you edit your post to add more information on OS flavor and version, freerdp version, and current screen configuration (output of `xrandr` e.g.)?

Comment: Added more info

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem on i3wm using Arco Linux and FreeRDP version 2.3.2. It looks like you want one window in the tiling window manager to cover both screens.

#### 1. Create a command for bspwm that toggles global fullscreen.

In i3, this meant adding a line to the config file:

```
bindsym $<key combination> fullscreen toggle global (I used $mod+Shift+f).
```

I hope it's similar in bspwm, but I'm not very familiar with it. From the little I know, you'll probably want to make a keyboard shortcut for it.

#### 2. Launch FreeRDP with the -grab-keyboard option so that your WM's command to toggle global fullscreen is available.

```
xfreerdp -grab-keyboard /multimon /monitors:0,1 /f ...
```

#### 3. Focus the FreeRDP window and run the global fullscreen command